# How do I deal with the "|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field" error message?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am making a web app with a few pages. On one of the pages, I would like to have a form that looks something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsOJ6.jpg

However I keep getting an error message saying:

> raise CrispyError('|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or
>   inexistent field') crispy_forms.exceptions.CrispyError:
>   |as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field
>   [10/Jul/2019 23:21:12] "GET /year2 HTTP/1.1" 500 148042

Here is my year2.html which appears to be where the error occurs:

```py
{% extends "HelloDjangoApp/layout.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

**HelloDjangoApp/year2.html**

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    {{ form.job_title|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ form.bio|as_crispy_field }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Calculate</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

For context, here is my views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render   # Added for this step
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import Person

class PersonCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Person
    fields = ('name', 'email', 'job_title', 'bio')


def index(request):
    now = datetime.now()

    return render(
        request,
        "HelloDjangoApp/index.html",  # Relative path from the 'templates' folder to the template file
        # "index.html", # Use this code for VS 2017 15.7 and earlier
        {
            'title' : "Exam Results Calculator",
            'message' : "Hello!",
            'content' : " on " + now.strftime("%A, %d %B, %Y at %X"),
        }
    )

def about(request):
    return render(
        request,
        "HelloDjangoApp/about.html",
        {
            'title' : "Simply enter your scores to find out your average",
            'content' : "Example app page for Django."
        }
    )

def year1(request):
    return render(
        request,
        "HelloDjangoApp/year1.html",
        {
            'title' : "1st Year Average",
            'content' : "First Year Stuff"

        }

    )

def year2(request):
    return render(
        request,
        "HelloDjangoApp/year2.html",
        {
            'title' : "2nd Year Average",
            'content' : "Second Year Stuff"

        }

    )


def year3(request):
    return render(
        request,
        "HelloDjangoApp/year3.html",
        {
            'title' : "3rd Year Average",
            'content' : "3rd Year Stuff"

        }

    )

def year4(request):
    return render(
        request,
        "HelloDjangoApp/year4.html",
        {
            'title' : "4th Year Average",
            'content' : "4th Year Stuff"

        }

    )
# Create your views here.
```

AND my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=130)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck your CBV - PersonCreateView.
Form fields which you are accessing in year2.html are not part of form instance of the View which is handling it.To correct this,
1) Rename your year2.html template to Person_form.html 
2) Remove "HelloDjangoApp/year2.html" from year2 function based view.

Hope this helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `return` the `render` with `{'form': form}` in all functions

Do this:

```
def year2(request):
    form = Person()
    return render(
        request,
        "HelloDjangoApp/year2.html",
        {
            'form': form
        }

    )
```